# How to display only map version in google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I don't want to display the satellite version,I want to display only the map version by default.(You will see those options on top-right.).Here is my code which displays both satellite and map version:

```
     <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
            /*for first time when radio button not selected*/
             myMap('15.835015', '74.517537');
             $('input[type=radio][name=browser]').change(function() {
                 var lat = $(this).data('lat');
                 var long = $(this).data('long');
                 myMap(lat, long)
             });
         });

         function myMap(lat, long) {
             var mapOptions = {
                 center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
                 zoom: 25,
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
             }
             var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 map: map
             });

         }

      </script>
```

Comment: If i am not wrong, you need to use mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

`mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID`

to:

`mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP`

Here is the Google Maps Docs for [MapTypeControlOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MapTypeControlOptions).